# Word analogy - terrify is to frighten as

Tags: vocabulary, analogy

Terrify is to frighten as...

1. demand is to request
2. explore is to ignore
3. brag is to scold
4. predator is to prey
5. chase is to capture

Please choose the closest option.

Comment: A dictionary will help you answer this.

Comment: While such questions can certainly be valuable teaching aids, they do not focus on a single point for discussion, and involve logic as well as pure linguistics. Intensified synonyms are involved here. The 'homework-/school-exercise-' style format is also not suitable for ELU.

Answer (score 1):

**Terrify is to frighten as...**

- demand is to request

**Terrifying** someone is usually a more intense way of scaring someone compared to just **frightening** them.
A **demand** is a more forceful/more intense kind of **request**.

The rest of the options don't make sense at all in this context.

Comment: I explained above why the question was off-topic here, and gave the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But given that this is one of OP’s first answers they probably started working on it before you posted your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too eager. Should I remove the answer? Does this entire question get removed if it doesn't meet the criteria of the site?

Comment: It's best. But please look at the Help Center to get a feel for site requirements. Looking at some answers by say John Lawler should give pointers towards the standards aspired to.

Comment: Your answer is correct and helpful, but if it gets upvoted, it can prevent the question from being deleted either by the OP or the automatic system. That is why a lot of people answer questions that are likely to be closed with a comment instead. Don’t get discouraged - it takes a while to get a feel for what each site’s “best practices” are.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I was wondering why so many questions ended up being answered in the comments instead of through answers, now it makes sense.